# Load File from Google Drive into a form using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Currently, I want to buld a form using apps script. Then we want to load the file from Google Drive into this form.

All result will be showed in the form as a link.

However, until now, I still don't have any function for loading file from drive.

I appreciate your helps on this case.
Thanks,
KN

Comment: Clarify please. So you want to add link to some file on Drive to form?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question well, I think you want to load the CONTENTS of a(ny) file into a widget on a form.

Unfortunally, using GAS for building an UiApp this is not possible.
You can show images and plain textfiles and several other types, but not **all** files.
If you try to show html-files, you will only see texts. No pictures, no links etc.

```
//   list of HTML tags that are permitted:
//     B, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, CENTER, CAPTION, CITE, CODE, DIV, EM, 
//     H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HR, I, LABEL, LEGEND, LI, OL, P, SPAN,
//     STRONG, SUB, SUP, TABLE, TBODY, TD, THEAD, TITLE, TR, TT, UL
```

This occurs because Caja strips out everythings else.

In have been trying to do the same (recently) but I ended up with 'beter do something else'.
So I decided to create a flextable containing files and I created an anchor for each file. Doing that, the user can click on a file and it opens.

If you want to refer to files on the drive you can create links containing

```
 var driveUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=';
```

and combine this with the fileId to `urlFile` for an anchor.

```
   var row = 0;
   var flxTable = app.createFlexTable();
   var files    = DriveApp.getFiles();
   while (files.hasNext())
   {
      var file     = files.next();
      var fileId   = file.getId();
      var fileName = file.getName();
      var urlFile  = driveUrl + fileId;
      var anchor   = app.createAnchor(fileName, urlFile);
      flxTable.setWidget(row++, 0, anchor);
   }
```

Probably you will have far too many files to show them using the code above (it just takes too long to load), so you have to take care just showing files that are required to see **at that time** and load others afterwards.